# How to call class constructor having its name in text variable? [Python]

Tags: python, constructor, exec

Let's assume we have some classes defined and available in global namespace. In example:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Vector:
    def __init__(self, alpha, r):
        self.x = r * cos(alpha)
        self.y = r * sin(alpha)

# and many others...
```

How to do this:

```
class_name = 'Point'
x = 14.361
y = -8.100
code_str = 'class_object = ' + class_name + '(' + str(x) + ', ' + str(y) + ')'

exec code_str  # That evaluates to: "class_object = Point(14.361, -8.100)"

print class_object.x, class_object.y
```

without using the dangerous exec?

PS. I'm intending to load the data from some txt or json file if anyone asks.

Comment: Load what data, the strings to execute? Looks like a bad idea.

Comment: You don't need `exec` at all. Just load your data from your text file, and pass it to the `Point` class constructor. Simple.

Comment: i know that executing code from file is VERY bad idea :) but i have many classes - Point, Line, Versor, and I don't know in advance which one I will call

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the class is defined or imported in the same module, you could use something like :

```
globals()[class_name](x, y)
```

if you have many classes to handle, you should better use a dictionnary to store them, key is the name, value is the class,

then you can call it with :

```
my_classes = {'Point' : Point, 'Point2' : Point2}

class_name = 'Point'
x = 14.361
y = -8.100
my_classes[class_name](x, y)
```

Answer (score 4):

Provided that a class is defined in (or imported into) the global namespace, you can get a reference to it via the dictionary returned by [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals). After that just create an instance the usual way, e.g.:

```
class_name = 'Point'
kwargs = {'x': 14.361, 'y': -8.100}
Point = globals()[class_name]
point = Point(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Does this work if I import a module? `import foo; foo_class_instance = globals()["foo.some_class_defined_in_foo"]();` (semi colons indicate end of line).

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval.

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x+100
        self.y = y+100

class_name = 'Vector'

x = 10
y = 20
caller = '{}({},{})'.format(class_name,x,y)
ob = eval(caller)

print ob.x, ob.y
```

Comment: Or just `ob = eval(class_name)(x, y)`.