# Create objects in Python based on file

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm coding a game in Python 3 and I need to create an unknown number of objects with each objects properties based on the contents of a file.

To explain, I'll dump some code here:

```
class attack(object):
    def __init__(self, name, power):
        self.name = name
        self.element = int(power)

import getline from linecache

Attacks = []

count = 1
while 1==1:
  line=getline("Attacks.txt", count)
  line = line.rstrip()
  if line == "":
    break
  else:
    linelist = line.split()
    #something involving "attack(linelist[1], linelist[2])"
    Attacks.append(item)
  count += 1
```

"Attacks.txt" contains this:

```
0 Punch 2
1 Kick 3
2 Throw 4
3 Dropkick 6
4 Uppercut 8
```

When the code is done, the list "Attacks" should contain 5 attack objects, one for each line of "Attacks.txt" with the listed name and power. The name is for the user only; in the code, each object will only be called for by its place in its list.

The idea is that the end user can change "Attacks.txt" (and other similar files)  to add, remove or change entries; that way, they can modify my game without digging around in the actual code.

The issue is I have no idea how to create objects on the fly like this or if I even can. I already have working code that builds a list from a file; the only problem is the object creation.

My question, simply put, is how do I do this?

Comment: You are probably looking into the `Factory Pattern`. Furthremore, attacks contain `behaviors`, not `objects`

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't be using a while-loop with `linecache.getline`, since you are essentially iterating over every line, just do `with open(<filename>) as f: for line in f:` And certainly, if you *were* going to do a while-loop, don't do `while 1==1`, just do `while True`

Comment: What doesn't work about `attack(linelist[1], linelist[2])`? It seems to me that's basically what you want, just maybe convert the second argument to `int`: `attack(linelist[1], int(linelist[2]))`. That and iterate over your file sanely, like I mentioned in the first comment...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That worked. I was overthinking it like an idiot. I assumed I needed some special trick to let me loop this and avoid naming each object; it seems that isn't actually a problem. Thank you.

Comment: @qwertyu63 seriously though, use a forloop and ditch `linecache`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes...seem like an overkill. I will delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem someday:

[How to call class constructor having its name in text variable? [Python]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848928/how-to-call-class-constructor-having-its-name-in-text-variable-python)

You obviously have to define classes which names are in file. I assume that is done. And you need to have them in current module namespace `globals()`

```
from somelib import Punch, Kick, Throw, Dropkick, Uppercut

globals()[class_name](x, y)
line = getline("Attacks.txt", count)
line = line.rstrip()
linelist = line.split()

class_name = linelist[1]
value = linelist[2]

class_object = globals()[class_name]
item = class_object(value)

# or shortly in one line:
# item = globals()[linelist[1]](linelist[2])
```

Comment: ok, now i see the question was simpler than that - you already know that any object whould be of the same class

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class like so providing overloading operators to support the operations:

```
class Operation:
   def __init__(self, *header):
      self.__dict__ = dict(zip(['attack', 'power'], header))
class Attack:
   def __init__(self, *headers):
     self.__dict__ = {"attack{}".format(i):Operation(*a) for i, a in enumerate(headers, start=1)}
   def __setitem__(self, attack_type, new_power):
      self.__dict__ = {a:Operation(attack_type, new_power) if b.attack == attack_type else b for a, b in self.__dict__.items()}
   def __getitem__(self, attack):
      return [b.power for _, b in self.__dict__.items() if b.attack == attack]
   @property
   def power_listings(self):
      return '\n'.join(['{} {}'.format(*[b.attack, b.power]) for _, b in self.__dict__.items()])

with open('filename.txt') as f:
    f = [i.strip('\n').split() for i in f]
a = Attack(*f)
print(a.power_listings)
a['Throw'] = 6 #updating the power of any occurrence of Throw
```

Output:

```
Throw 6
Kick 3
Punch 2
Uppercut 8
Dropkick 6
```